# Replace text of ASP Literal in Code Behind

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm new to ASP and was hoping to get some guidance on how to make my literal accessible in my Code Behind and then change it to the text of a passed in parameter.

I have an resources.ascx file that displays a list of people (pulled from a database). That is working fine and it looks something like this:

> Full name
>
> T: (888-888-8888)
>
> F: (888-888-8888)

The problem, however, is that I now want it conditionally say "Toll Free" instead of "F:" for one page.

In the **people.aspx** page, I'm passing in "Toll Free" to the resource:

```
<%@ Register Src="~/UserControls/resources.ascx" TagName="Resources" TagPrefix="ucResources" %>    
<ucResources:Resources ID="Resources1" FaxNumberAlias="Toll Free" runat="server" />
```

**resources.ascx** The repeater outputs all the people from the database to the page.

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
    <div class="sectioncontent">
        <b><%#Eval("EmployeeFirstName")%> <%#Eval("EmployeeLastName)%></b>
        T: <%#Eval("Phone")%>
        <br>
        <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="FaxNumberLabel">F:</asp:Literal> <%#Eval("Fax")%><br>
    </div>
    <br />
</ItemTemplate>
```

In the **resources.ascx.vb** file, I wanna do something like this but FaxNumberLabel (the literal I declared in resources.ascx) isn't accessible or hasn't been declared.

```
Public Property FaxNumberAlias() As String
    Get
        Return _FaxNumberAlias
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _FaxNumberAlias = value
    End Set
End Property

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(_FaxNumberAlias) Then
        FaxNumberLabel.Text = _FaxNumberAlias
    End If
    PopulateRepeater()
End Sub
```

What am I missing that connects the literal to the code behind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the `Literal` is inside a `Repeater` so you may potentially have lots of them. The best way is to access them inside the `OnDataItemBound` event of your repeaters:

```
Protected Sub Repeater1_OnDataItemBound(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.OnDataItemBound
    If (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item) Or _
        (e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem) Then

        Dim litFaxNumberLabel As Literal = e.Item.FindControl("FaxNumberLabel")

        litFaxNumberLabel.Text = _FaxNumberAlias

    End If

End Sub
```

Note: Excuse any bad syntax, it's been over 4 years since I touched VB!

Comment: Thanks! I found somewhat of an answer with more searching but didn't completely solve it until I got your answer. I was missing the `Handles Repeater1.ItemDataBound` part and I was having trouble figuring out where `RepeaterItemEventArgs` comes from.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use like this -

```
        protected void DataDisplay_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item) || (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem))
        {
            LinkButton lit = (LinkButton)e.Item.FindControl("LinkButton2");
            if (lit.Text == "0")
            {
                int a = Convert.ToInt32(lit.Text);
                if (a == 0)
                {
                    if (a == 0)
                    {
                        lit.Text = "Your Text";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I am using a button (btnRedirect) in each row.

```
       RepeaterItem item = btnRedirect.NamingContainer as RepeaterItem;
       var type = item.FindControl("IdUsed") as Literal;
       var literalValue = type.Text;
```